# problema com prompt de comando php,o código php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 não funciona no servidor(wamp),já tentei de tudo que eu pesquisei,pórem dá erro 404

Tags: php, wampserver

o código é executado na página fashion.html
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uVlM.png
resultado do código
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsBEP.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tá faltando o `index.php` na raiz do seu projeto.
Mas você pode ver o conteúdo da tua página acessando:

http://localhost:8080/fashion.html

Comment: ,o index.php está na pasta raiz,eu editei a pergunta e coloque a foto do código do prompt,se vc puder olhar eu agradeço.

Comment: Editei a resposta.